# Convert Runtime-Attributes Size, Point, Rect

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios5.1

I'm using "User Defined Runtime Attributes" for my custom classes in IB.

I catch the values in:
-(void) setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key

How do I convert values for Size, Point and Rect?

NSLog(@"value %@", value)

for Size writes: "value NSSize: {10, 10}"

But isn't NSSize only a datatype for OSX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a mistake in Apple's framework.  The description is simply outputting NSSize instead of CGSize.  You can use it like this `[value CGSizeValue]` etc.  NSSize doesn't even exist on iOS so it is impossible that you are dealing with it.

You can verify this with one line -> `NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10)]);`